# Matrix search for value

Tags: matlab, search, coordinates

I am describing the logical steps I am trying to figure out how to code.

1. Read a 1000x1000 matrix file
2. Create 200x200 matrix in 1000x1000 matrix file provided with an origin and time stamp from another file
3. Search 200x200 matrix for variable `x`,
4. if found: name found item, output into new matrix: name, location(s) of variable `x` and time stamp, or one pixel item.

So far I have been able to read the 1000x1000, but when creating the xmax and ymin from the (x,y) origin I get a location that looks like it starts at 1,1.
Instead of where it found it in the 200x200 square I tried to define somewhere within the 1000,1000.

Tried so far:

```
num = xlsread(TestCase.xlsx);
A=TestCase100;
shipX=20; shipy=20;
xposmin=(shipX-10); xposmax=(shipX+10);
RADAR= A([xposmin:xposmax],[yposmin:yposmax]);
```

Comment: Some code of what you have so far/tried would be useful.

Comment: num = xlsread(TestCase.xlsx);
A=TestCase100
Shipx=20; shipy=20;
xposmin=(shipX-10); xposmax=(shipX+10);
RADAR= A([xposmin:xposmax],[yposmin:yposmax]);

Comment: This is what I have so far..

Comment: I am really confused here, you say that you want a 200x200 sqaure ans then you define a 20x20 square starting at 10, are you sure you are not just mixing up values since (10,10) is close to (1,1) in a 1000x1000 matrix. Also Radar should be a 20x20 matrix here. Also try `a = [11,12,13,14;21,22,23,24;31,32,33,34;41,42,43,44]; a([2:3],[2:3])` and you will see it works perfectly

Comment: i used those values as a test case.  thanks for your input- appreciate your suggestion